# Modify database for the SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Search administration web site

Tags: sharepoint, search

Does anyone know how to modify the database settings for the Enterprise Search administration web site?  When you configure the service application via Central Administration, SharePoint just decides to use the default database server and gives a name like *Search_Service_DB_Identifier*.  I want to modify this to atleast give a name that makes scense like SharePoint_Search_AdministrationWebContent, and it might be nice to move it to the database server that is hosting the crawl and property database.

I figured out how to move the Central Administration web content database, but this database is not listed as a content database.  It is listed as a Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchAdminDatabase.  I have not tested to see if the same process would work but because you are doing a RemoveContentDatabase and NewContentDatabase, I would assume not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SharePoint seems to 'helpfully' set up a lot of things automatically.  In most cases I delete the auto generated service applications and re-create them with the exact settings I want (including sanitised server & DB names). Much easier than moving things that are already provisioned.  Is this a new set-up or are all these elements already live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topic of renaming SharePoint 2010 databases is also discussed on [SharePoint Overflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2485/guidance-on-renaming-the-multitude-of-databases-generated-by-sharepoint-2010).